# where to set locale_backend to comply with new changes in money-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, money-rails

The money-rails gem will throw the following warning

```
 [DEPRECATION] You are using the default localization behaviour that will change in the next major release. Find out more - https://github.com/RubyMoney/money#deprecation
```

The documentation says to set:

```
 Money.locale_backend = :i18n
```

And, the add:

```
en:
  number:
    currency:
      format:
      delimiter: ","
      separator: "."

# falling back to
number:
  format:
    delimiter: ","
    separator: "."
```

updating the en.yml file is self explanatory.  But, the documentation is not clear as to where to set Money.locale_backend = :i18n.

Should this be in a new initializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it in `config/initializers/money.rb`